# Changing default charset to latin

Tags: mysql

When I change the default charset from UTF-8 to latin1, it changes the text, varchar columns to utf8
So the new table looks something like this...

```
...
  `include_zoneclass` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
...
  PRIMARY KEY (`campaignid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2082 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

How do I make the table totally latin1 and no trace of utf8 should be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the ALTER TABLE command with CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET

See here for more:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html